# Psexec to windows server 2012 only starts process, not GUI

Tags: psexec

I need to run a program called Kodi in windows server 2012 from another machine,
The startkodi.bat itself works correctly in the win server machine

```
C:\PSTools\psexec -u Administrator -p 123456 \\192.168.0.148 -s -d cmd.exe /c "C:\startkodi.bat"
```

But when i run this it only gives me

```
Starting PSEXESVC service on 192.168.0.148...
cmd.exe started on 192.168.0.148 with process ID 4460.
```

But when i remote it i dont see any instance of Kodi running,

BUT it does open a Kodi process in task manager...

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Ok i'll post there... i saw a similar question about PSEXEC so i thought i'd ask here